# Is there any harm updating the Content Type of Folder to the specific Document Set using Flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, power-automate, powerapp, best-practices

I have a requirement where I need to create a new document set using Power Apps. Now, that is not supported by PowerApps SubmitForm() function.

So I have built a flow that first creates the folder and then updates the content type ID to the content type of Document Set. This serves the purpose.

But I am concerned about the OOTB triggers or functions which are handled by SharePoint for the specific content types.

Is there any harm or functionality loss risk if we first create a folder and then change its content type to something else?

What is the best practice to achieve the above requriement?